# Sulu cache always misses

Tags: symfony, sulu

I'm attempting to set up caching Sulu CMS pages. Locally I have set the environment to prod (tried with dev but switched to prod in case this was the problem), but with cache debug turned on.

config/packages/sulu_http_cache.yaml looks like this:

```
sulu_http_cache:
    proxy_client:
        symfony:
            enabled: true
        debug:
            enabled: true
```

config/packages/prod/cache.yaml looks like this

```
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.filesystem
        system: cache.adapter.system
```

The cache directories exist in my /var directory, but they are empty

All responses have the following headers:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cache always misses it is a hint that you are accessing a `session` inside your request. The following in Symfony will automatically start a session e.g.:

- using a csrf token (`csrf_token`)
- configure unlazy firewall on the route (check your `security_website.yaml`)
- accessing flash message or other things like that (`app.flashes`)
- accessing session itself (`app.session`)
- accessing current user (`app.user`)

As a session access indicates that the "response" is user specific and not the same for every visitor symfony will set the response to private and so it always a cache miss.

Edit your code that you are not longer accessing a session and that the `Cache-Control` Header responses with "public" that the HttpCache Component will cache this response.

As mention by you the symfony auto behaviour can be disabled by using:

```
$response->headers->set(AbstractSessionListener::NO_AUTO_CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER, 1);
```

I personally would avoid this as it could cache security specific data or example write a cached username out in your html which you don't want.

Another way would use the UserContext Based Caching this means that for example every Role has its own Cache for example. A documentation about this can be found:

- https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.2/cookbook/user-context-caching.html
- https://foshttpcachebundle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/user-context.html

This is mostly used when your application has security on the website, and only specific roles can view specific routes.

Comment: thanks for this - you are right, the way we were dealing with sessions activated the session on every request. I did try to remove this, however the cache still seemed to miss every time. in the end, I manually overrode the caching header (on certain static pages) by doing the following:

$response->headers->set(AbstractSessionListener::NO_AUTO_CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER, 1);

Comment: @JamieMaxwell I added that and user specific caching. Please feel free to mark it as accepted answer, to let other know what was wrong here.